# Can't call a Activity class methods from instance

Tags: android-activity, instance

I'm starting learning android development , but I cant understand , why I can not call a Activity class methods from instance , for example :

this code doesnt work :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void test(){
        Activity a = new Activity();
        a.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: How doesn't the code work? You need to show us the error message or describe what's going wrong. Also, it appears you are missing a closing curly brace. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple explanation would be that since `a` in the general case could be an of the type `Activity` *or any subclass* of `Activity` and *class methods are not part of any interface*, the compiler cannot at compile time know that all subclasses of Activity actually implement OnCreate so it's actually callable.

You could argue that in this special case, the compiler can do statical analysis and figure the type out, but it would make for code that becomes invalid if you refactor the code to get the value of `a` from a function or passed in as a parameter.